# windows 2008 server spooler problem

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, network-printer, printing

i have one windows 2008 server & windows xp clients.

one HP2600n is connected to network with network cable, and installed in server and shared.

also same printer is shared on xp cleints.

the problem is: once cleints send print it come to the server que and stuck there untill we manually restart printer spooler service.

once we restart the service all the prints in QUE prints and after that new prints again stuck in QUE till next manually restart.

how can we solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What driver do you have installed for the printer on the server? It looks like there's no W2K8 driver for that model. You might want to try HP's universal print driver.

Comment: i try to find HP's universal print driver for server 2008 but i did't find any one, can you please send me link to downlaod.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This model of printer uses a host based driver. Should not be installed on a print server. The UPD will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find HP's Universal print drivers is to go to HP's driver download page (http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/support.html).  Then put in something like 'Laserjet 4200dtn'.  This will bring up a list asking you what OS do you want the driver for.  Click on the 'Microsoft Windows 7 (32-bit)' and/or 'Microsoft Windows 7 (64-bit)'.  This will bring up a new page that if one scrolls down there will find the latest Universal drivers.